# Access denied for keka@localhost using password YES [Navicat & EasyPHP]

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, wamp

Buenos dias cuando intento una nueva conexión MySQL en Navicat:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me ocurre que:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando EasyPHP 14.1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando en vez de ponerle a la conexión un usuario y contraseña específicos, lo dejo como viene por defecto: user root, pass ninguna, si que me funciona y se conecta todo. Sin embargo necesito un usuario y contraseña que no sean esos, ya que estoy intentando conectar mi pagina web con la base de datos en Navicat. He estado buscando en internet pero las soluciones que aportan son para Xampp y Wamp, y no se como aplicarlas a EasyPHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz creado el usuario keka previamente? 
Si no es así, puedes crearlo desde navicat ingresando con el usuario root y entrando al menú **Users** > **New User**. 
Otorgandole los privilegios correspondientes ya podras ingresar con el.